# JavaScript Object to JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I've got a JavaScript object where I've pushed values...

```
var myObject = [];
myObject.name = "Steve"
myObject.job = "Driver"
```

Now I want to get those values as JSON, i.e.

```
{ "name": "Steve", "job": "Driver" }
```

is this possible? I've tried JSON stringify but it returns an empty object

Comment: Also note that what you have in your expected output isn't JSON.  JSON requires keys to be quoted.

Comment: @Brad fixed. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure why anyone is downvoting this question.  It's a completely valid question, with example code, expected output, and what was tried...

Answer (score 8):

`var myObject = [];` should be `var myObject = {};`

Answer (score 3):

For starters, make sure you're creating an [*object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) not an [*array*.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) An array is an ordered list of data where as an object is an unordered group of key-value pairs. As such, they're serialized differently.

```js
var myObject = {}; // <-- Changed [] to {}
myObject.name = "Steve";
myObject.job = "Driver";

// Alternatively, you can do this
var myObject = {
  name: 'Steve',
  job: 'Driver'
};
```

Converting it to JSON is as easy as calling `JSON.stringify`.

```js
var myObject = {
  name: 'Steve',
  job: 'Driver'
};

var json = JSON.stringify(myObject);
console.log(json);
```